# How to take inputs in different variables in one line of code in Java?

Tags: java

Suppose in a Java code,

```
{        
double a, b, c;      
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    
a = sc.nextDouble();      
b = sc.nextDouble();      
c = sc.nextDouble();   
}
```

Since `sc.nextDouble();` is common to all the variables, what can I do to reduce the lines of code (without using array)?

Comment: Don't. 3 lines of code is fine.

Comment: Why would you want to reduce this anyway? It's exactly what's happening and nothing that could be done would improve readability.

Comment: Fun fact: the compiler ignores line breaks. So... in theory, we could remove all line breaks, reducing the class to a single line...

Comment: If you want three separate variables, you have to deal with them separately.

Comment: Every time I see a question like this, I wonder whether people are still using floppy disks to save their code on (the 5.25" floppy disk, that actually were "floppy").

Comment: @Turing85 Actually, I am learning Java, so I am just wanting to know if there is any possibility to do such things....though I will not use such things in actual programming so don't care about readability, etc.

Answer (score 1):

When people say "reduce the number of lines", the fatuous answer is just to remove all the line breaks, because newlines have no semantic meaning anyway.

But what I think you might mean is "reduce the number of *statements*".

You can express the body of this block in just two statements, by declaring the variables and assigning them in a single statement:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    
double a = sc.nextDouble(),
       b = sc.nextDouble(),
       c = sc.nextDouble();
```

But there's no real advantage in doing this, as it doesn't actually reduce the duplication substantially; and style guides such as [Google's Java style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.8.2-variable-declarationshttps://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.8.2-variable-declarations) actively forbid declaring multiple variables in a single statement.

If you don't actually need them in separate variables, you could use an array:

```
double[] ds = new double[3];
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) ds[i] = sc.nextDouble();
```

but whilst this stops you repeating the `sc.nextDouble()`s, you have to introduce the loop gubbins instead.

What you had already was fine. The only thing I would change would be to declare and initialize the variables at the same time.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    
double a = sc.nextDouble();
double b = sc.nextDouble();
double c = sc.nextDouble();
```

Comment: Never knew the conventions! In practice I will obviously write according to what you said.

Answer (score -1):

If you are really bent on only writing `sc.nextDouble()` once, you could use an enum with an instance variable of type double set when the enum is initialized.

```java
public enum DoubleExample {
    A, B, C;   
    public final double value;
    private DoubleExample() { value = new Scanner(System.in).nextDouble(); }
}
```

Of course, if you use this solution, the values of `A`, `B`, and `C` can't be modified after creation. Also, since a separate Scanner is used for each double assignment, each double must be entered on a new line, and some resources are leaked for each variable initialized.

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jhale1805/ce83ede36338486dd4957d5f8fca31f5) with a full runnable example.